# How to assign a variable as fieldname holder when using doc.data(). in firebase to retrieve data

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to recieve data from firebase cloud firestore. I have a collection called 'profiles', a doc called user and I have fields like favorite_music, favorite_book, favorite_movie. I want to recieve data based on an Input recieved from an html page.

I want to pass variable get on data.doc.get . How should I rewrite this code to make it work?

JS code

```
db.collection("profiles").doc("user").get().
then(snapshot => {
    snapshot.doc.forEach(
        doc => {
            displayfunction(doc)
        });
)
});

document.getElementById("hit")
    .addEventListener("submit", function() {
        var get = document.getElementById("fav").value;

        function displayfunction(doc) {
            let requested_item = document.createElement('p');
            requested_item.textContent = doc.data().get;
            var displayele = document.getElementById("display");
            displayele.appendChild(requested_item);
        }

    })
```

html code

```
<select id="fav">
<option value="favorite_music">my music</option>
<option value="favorite_book">my book</option>
</select>
<div id="display">
</div>
<button type="submit" id="hit"> submit </button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it. The problem with your code is that you were running the query at the top, independent of the `submit` event. Your `displayFunction` was also scoped to the `submit` handler, so it couldn't be invoked outside of that scope.

What you really want is to define a function that gets the documents--`getUserProfiles`--and call it on the `submit` event. You pass `getUserProfiles` a callback that does the work.

```
document.getElementById('hit').addEventListener('submit', function() {
  getUserProfiles(function displayFunction(doc) {
    const displayEl = document.getElementById('display');
    const requestedItem = document.createElement('p');
    const data = doc.data();

    requestedItem.textContent = data.whateverMyAttributeNameIs;

    displayEl.appendChild(requestedItem);
  });
});

function getUserProfiles(callback) {
  return db
    .collection('profiles')
    .doc('user')
    .get()
    .then(snapshot => {
      snapshot.doc.forEach(callback);
    });
}
```